# Is there a way to trigger a keyPressEvent in PyQt with a QKeyEvent coded in the script?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, event-handling

I'm going to try to explain this in the best way possible. I'm playing around with using different devices as input in PyQt. I'm trying to use EOG glasses as a device to interact with interfaces (sort of like an alternate version of a keyboard). And I'm trying to do some key mapping.

I want PyQt to take in an input and carry out the appropriate key press event. In this case, the input is a number e.g. I have a number randomly generated from 1-10 where each number represents a key press. Say 1 = left arrow key, how would I go about initialising this `QKeyEvent` in the code to eventually trigger the `keyPressEvent()` handler? (I want the left arrow key event to do what it normally does on the UI so I'm not calling a function or anything).

I've tried simply calling it:

```
case 1: # left arrow key
    QtGui.QKeyEvent(type=KeyPress, key=, modifiers=)
```

But I'm uncertain what the parameters would be (I'm not finding the documentation helpful as it isn't very detailed) and whether this would be correct in the first place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What should be more detailed? In the [QKeyEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html) documentation you can find what the [`key()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#key) or [`modifiers()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#modifiers) values could be. Besides, it's unclear what you're *actually* trying to do. Are you doing this for testing purposes? Do you want to trigger specific widget functions? Because "synthesized" events are rarely required (Qt does that only in very specific and peculiar cases) and should normally be avoided.

Comment: @musicamante My bad, I think I was looking at an outdated version of the documentation and didn't realise there was an updated one. I'm trying to do something similar to key mapping where pressing the "1" key would equate to a left arrow key press if that helps. But what I'm actually trying to do is seeing if I can call a key press event by not actually pressing the key. I'm just calling it in the code. I've updated the question to explain what the context is and why I'm doing this but I don't think it's really relevant.

Comment: Well, knowing the purpose or assuming it are different things: many people ask the wrong question for the wrong reason, which is clearly not your case (and now we know it :-) ). Note that you should normally not directly call the specific event handler, the *proper* way to "trigger" synthesized events is by using the application [`sendEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#sendEvent) and [`postEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent).